# Use Aspectj load-time weaving on provided dependencies?

Tags: jboss, aspectj

I was following the instructions in https://access.redhat.com/solutions/328513 to test out load-time weaving and I've got the example working without much of an issue.

My issue comes in when I want to weave a dependency that's already provided on the classpath as a JBoss module. I'm trying to gather some performance metrics from one of my project's dependencies but that dependency `<scope>provided</scope>` since it's already bundled with JBoss.

I can see weaving happen when I do something like `@Pointcut("execution(* com.mypackage..*(..))")` (so I know it's working on some level) but if I try `@Pointcut("execution(* org.slf4j..*(..))")` nothing gets woven.

I imagine there's something different happening for modules vs. war/ear deployments but I'm not familiar enough with the classloading process to make much headway. I would assume that since my aspects are provided as a global-module it would be loaded before any other module and then be able to affect their weaving but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Can anyone provide insight as to what's going on here?